# How to carry out the following sparse matrix subtraction?

Tags: python, arrays, sparse-matrix

I am trying to do the following array subtraction in Python:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])  
b = a[:, None] - a[None, :]
sum_ = np.sum(b, axis=-1)
print(sum_)
```

The above seems to work. However, if I change the above array `a` to a sparse matrix:

```
a = csr_matrix(a)
```

and do the above steps exactly, I get an error:

```
IndexError: Index dimension must be <= 2
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` style broadcasting has not been implemented for sparse matrices. `a[:, None]` is not supported for sparse matrices and, in your subtraction, `a[:, None]` and `a[None, :]` have different shapes.

Your sparse matrix subtraction can be obtained if you do the broadcasting prior to converting into a sparse matrix, and if both parts of the subtraction have the same shape. For example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 1]])
c = csr_matrix(a) - csr_matrix(b)
sum = np.sum(c)
print(csr_matrix.toarray(c))
print(sum)
```